# how to integrate VoIP in android application?

Tags: android, android-networking

I want to make free calling application through net to mobile or land line call using VoIP. I have not much knowledge of VoIP. I get inspiration from using some application like line,Skype,etc. how can I achieve domestic and international call using VoIP in android application. I search lot about but I cannot get direct and easy to understand resource to get this task. so if any one have any idea or resource then most well come to achieve this task of my application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [WebRTC](http://www.webrtc.org/home),and here are compiling steps [Getting Started](http://www.webrtc.org/reference/getting-started), there is an working example project, WebRTCDemo for Android, where you can check how it's working. I used it in the real program, not just googled and answered, and it works perfectly well, also has STUN, TURN support.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the Android SIP API to implement VoIP : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/sip.html

Here is a great tutorial : http://www.basic4ppc.com/android/forum/threads/android-sip-voip-tutorial.13088/

If you want to use 3rd party libraries,this one is good : http://www.sipdroid.org/

Answer (score 0):

You can look at [CSipSimple](https://code.google.com/p/csipsimple/) source code

Comment: If it too complicated to understand CSipSimple source code you can have a look at Google demo for SIP https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/nist-sip/+/8d001cf4f3910159e2c74109ac6c3eebedd1d036/demo/com/android/sip/demo